# How to retrieve all blob files only once when one or multiple blob files are updated?

Tags: azure-functions, blob, azure-blob-trigger

I have about 15 text blob files in the same container. They are not very large (a max of 350 KB). There will be very rare updates to these files (some or all) maybe once in months. When any of these are updated, I need to send all these files to a Web API. With BlobTrigger, I end up sending the files multiple times (one time for each trigger). How do I check or wait for all the triggers to complete and then send the files? Or is there some other approach that can check that if any file is changed, then I should retrieve them all and send it to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Azure Event Grid for blob storage eventing with an EventGridTrigger function for subscriber.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I had looked into it but your answer confirms to me that that is the path to take for this case.